# How should my new light fixture be connected to these wires?

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture, electronics

I thought this would be a really quick job. One live wire, one neutral wire, and one ground wire. Cut the power, hook up the 3 wires, turn on the power…

The problem was that when i opened up the junction box it was all weird looking.

I see the live and neutral wires (which i’m assuming are the red and black wires) that are running along the ceiling and coming in from the side (on the left). But then coming out of the ceiling is a what looks like a portable lamp cord… that appears to be acting as a ground. The problem is that this cord has two cables (if you look close you can see that it’s pulled apart near the ceiling), not one cable, like a normal ground. Additionally, when i first opened it up, one of these “ground” cables was connected to the black cable on the left (the one that runs along the ceiling).

This all looks really weird to me compared to what i thought i would see. And from what i had figured out, ground and neutral were not supposed to be bonded except at the main panel. So that seemed dangerous.

I was wondering if anyone else has seen this or if there’s a simple thing i can do to figure this out (i have a voltage meter).

Thank you to anyone that has thoughts about this situation.

See pics below[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How was the original fixture connected before you pulled it all apart?

Comment: Pull out the switch and check the wires.  If same wire then it is being used as a switch loop, but should be connected to the live wire if using lamp cord is legal(I doubt it).  If black is neutral, then switching neutral is not good.  Live will show house voltage(220) to neutral and ground.  Neutral will/should show 0 volts to ground.

Comment: I added an image that describes how it was connected previously. The main reason that i was concerned was that i know that the person that did it before was just winging it, and it showed once i got in there. I just want to make sure that i’m doing things correctly this time around.

Comment: Have you opened up the box with the switch which controls this light? Would it be a good guess if I said that the "lamp cord" is connected to that switch?

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I’m heading back over to that house later today and i’m going to look inside the switch. But if it is that brown cable that wired to it… what should be the correct setup? Concerning how it was wired previously that seemed incorrect.